# Clear timeouts in array if they exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout, cleartimeout

For the life of me I can't figure out how to clear timeouts in an array if they exist.

I have a single page app(SPA) website(http://www.rock3t.ca/) and the ID's grow every time you click "Home" very fast, which doesn't seem to cancel the timeouts. Visit the site and you will see the slogan under the logo in the center changing at a very fast pace and then slowing down. Click on "Home" multiple times quick to see how it reacts. It hasn't cleared, you will notice blips.

```
//slogans
function loadSlogans(){

    //slogan timeouts
    var sloganTimeouts = [];

    //slogans
    var slogans = ['Websites', 'Apps', 'Media', 'Code', 'SEO', 'CRM','Ads','Flyers','Logos','Games','Streams','Web','Websites', 'Apps', 'Media', 'Code', 'SEO', 'CRM','Ads','Flyers','Logos','Games','Streams','Web'];

    var sloganTime = 100;
    var sloganTimeFade = 0;
    var slogans_length = slogans.length;
    var sloganHalfTime = slogans_length / 2;

    //clear slogan timeouts
    $(slogans).each(function(i){

        //clear timeout if exists
        if(typeof sloganTimeouts[i] !== "undefined"){
          clearTimeout(sloganTimeouts[i]);
        }
    });

    //slogan timeout
    function runSloganTimeout(i) {

        //easing out time when half way
        if(i > sloganHalfTime){
            sloganTimeFade++;
            sloganTime = (i * 100) + (sloganTimeFade * 100) * (sloganTimeFade / 4);
        }else{
            sloganTime = i * 100;
        }

        //set timeouts
        sloganTimeouts[i] = setTimeout(function(){

            //append slogans
            $('#slogan span').html(slogans[i]);

        },sloganTime);
    }

    //each slogan
    $(slogans).each(function(i){

        //run
        runSloganTimeout(i);
    });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has cleared, but previous process hasn't over, so you will not clear all upcoming timeouts.
One of the solutions: add **processId** global var and interrupt the previous process.
See my example:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oJDfDYLyp599METwnJc6?p=preview)

```
var processId = 0;

//slogans
function loadSlogans(){

    processId++;

    var selfProcessId = processId;

    //slogan timeouts
    ...
    //slogans
    ...
    //clear slogan timeouts
    ...

    //slogan timeout
    function runSloganTimeout(i) {
        //easing out time when half way
        ...
        //set timeouts
        sloganTimeouts[i] = setTimeout(function(){
            //append slogans
            if( selfProcessId == processId )
                $('#slogan span').html(i+slogans[i]);

        },sloganTime);
    }

    //each slogan
    $(slogans).each(function(i){

        //run
        if( selfProcessId == processId )
            runSloganTimeout(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: Still does the same thing.

Comment: if i'm reading your code right, you don't need the if clauses. They will ALWAYS equal the same. Why have them?

Comment: Not always, they exist in different contexts. Have you tried pushing the button quickly, removing if clauses, tried it again?

Comment: I added the button to the site the same way you made it, and it works when being pushed. However when clicking home it doesn't, which technically should be the same thing.